# MySQL: insert into multiple columns using selects from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have a products catalog that is imported directly to a website's database. Each product row lists its Category and Subcategory. After the products are imported, I run this SQL to add the distinct categories to the database (which are used for creating navigation URLs based on their ids):

```
INSERT INTO categories (name) SELECT Distinct category FROM catalog_products;
```

Now, I want to add the subcategories as well to it's own table, but with a reference to the ID of it's parent Category, which is what I'm having trouble with.

Example: the product "SDH 20" belongs to the Category "Diagnose" (has an id 5 on the 'categories' table) and to the subcategory "Hematology". The 'subcategories' table will then have to list Hematology as having a categoryID of 5, which is the ID of "Diagnose" on the category table. Here is the SQL I've attempted:

```
INSERT INTO subcategories (name, idCategory) SELECT Distinct subcategory FROM catalog_products UNION ALL SELECT id from category WHERE categories.name = (SELECT catalog_products.category FROM catalog_products);
```

But I get a  `"#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"` error.

Is it possible to populate the 'subcategories' table's name and idCategory with one SQL that reads the catalog_products rows? If so, what is wrong with my SQL?

Comment: If you can, edit your question with a few rows of sample data and expected results or an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) as this will help other users recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'IN' if your subselect Returns more than one row:

```
INSERT INTO subcategories (name, idCategory) 
  SELECT Distinct subcategory FROM catalog_products 
  UNION ALL SELECT id from category WHERE 
  categories.name in (SELECT catalog_products.category FROM catalog_products);
                  ^^
```

Comment: Thank you Jens. But now I get the error "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". So looks like it's not finding all the 2 values it needs to insert into the table.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to split this SQL into two. First, populate the subcategories just as it was done with the categories: INSERT INTO subcategories (name) SELECT Distinct subcategory FROM catalog_products; After that then, UPDATE only the idCategory of the subcategories table. Trying to work on a SQL for that now but it's still somewhat tricky

Comment: @Robert can you show some examples, that whe can see what your SQL should do?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with one possible answer to my own question.

This was somewhat of a confusing query because it was dealing with 3 different tables at the same time, so  I tried splitting into two simpler SQLs.

First, just like the categories table, I added all the distinct subcategory name's without their parent categoryID field.

```
INSERT INTO subcategories (name) SELECT Distinct subcategory FROM catalog_products;
```

Now, I update the existing subcategories with the categoryID of their parent category with this SQL, that also target's the products catalog:

```
UPDATE subcategories SET idCategory = (SELECT categories.id FROM categories,catalog_products WHERE subcategories.name IN (Select  catalog_products.subcategory) AND categories.name IN (Select catalog_products.category));
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you have two tables:

```
CATEGORIES: id|name
CATALOG_PRODUCTS: product|category|subcategory
```

UNION ALL gives you two different rows instead of two values that you expect. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO subcategories (NAME, idCategory) 
SELECT cp.subcategory, c.categoryID FROM catalog_products AS cp 
JOIN categories AS c ON cp.category=c.name
GROUP BY cp.name
```

You just need to join both tables on name and if you want to DISTINCT use GROUP BY

Hope that helps. Have not tested this SQL so correct it a bit if needed